# joining two tables eventhough the id does not display on the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables NAMES and NAMES_VERIFICATIONS

**NAMES**

```
id     fname    Tax  
1      jack     56982
1000   Tim      32165
2321   Andrew   98956
231    Jim      11215
```

**NAMES_VERIFICATIONS**

```
id     idtype  iddata
1      tax      56982
1      passport 12365
2321   tax      98956
2321   passport 65656
```

so if you notice there is no ID 1000 in the NAMES_VERIFICATIONS table
so i want my result to be something like this

**Expected output**

```
NAMES.id   NAMES.fname  NAMES.TAX   NAMES_VERIFICATIONS.iddata
1          jack            56982     56982     
1000       Tim            32165      NULL
..
...
```

things i have tried was using left join like this

```
Select Names.id,Names.fname,NAMES.TAX,NAMES_VERIFICATIONS.iddata
FROM Names
LEFT JOIN NAMES_VERIFICATIONS 
ON Names.id = NAMES_VERIFICATIONS.id
WHERE NAMES.VERIFICATION.idtype = 'tax'
Order by Names.id
```

but the result i get is

**output**

```
NAMES.id   NAMES.fname  NAMES.TAX   NAMES_VERIFICATIONS.iddata
1          jack            56982     56982     
2321       Andrew          98956     98956
..
...
```

but i want it to also display IDS which are not present in NAMES_VERIFICATIONS

how do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the criteria in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join:

```sql
SELECT n.id, n.fname, n.TAX, nv.iddata
FROM Names n
LEFT JOIN NAMES_VERIFICATIONS nv
    ON n.id = nv.id AND nv.idtype = 'tax'
ORDER BY n.id;
```